# How To Login into Django admin from React JS Frontend Login Page

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to type the username and password in frontend and if the credintials are right redirect to django admin while being logged in and see the models and things inside django admin.

I created an API that enables users to log in and authenticate and log in to Django admin. It functions properly when I send a post request through rest_framework. However, when attempting to send a request through the frontend and redirect to django admin it fails to work and asking for the username and password.

```
`class LoginView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    # authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        username = serializer.validated_data['username']
        password = serializer.validated_data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)

            return Response({'message': 'Logged in successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

Comment: You are actually redirecting the user to the django admin and you are making him login in the react frontend , that is it totally absurd and this does not work this way.  If you want to do redirect him to the django admin panel with login you need to do something else . Try this , take the login credentials and then redirect to some backend page with the login credentials and then you can make that person login in the backend with those credentials and then again redirect to the django admin panel . This could be done easily and the way you are trying to go is not the way.

Comment: @Om Kashyap To get credit please show your answer rather than insults. Thank you